# getting Nth value of a linked list recursively

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I want to be able to be able to recursively pass `count` or increment count and then pass it into my recursion. However, I know I must declare `count = 0` to be able to use it when incrementing. I am still learning python and I am finding it hard to recursively increment count. Could someone help me with this please?

I know currently my code is wrong because each recursion i make, count will be resent to 0. I don't want to set count as a 3rd argument because I feel as though it is not necessary.

my code:

```
def getNth(head, n):
    count = 0
    if count == n:
        count += 1
        return head.value
    else:
        if head.next is not None:
            getNth(head.next,n)
        else:
            print 'not in linked list'
```

Comment: So why don't you pass the count variable as parameter as part of the recursive function call?

Comment: By the way, have you figured it out? Without parameter or global vars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count backwards rather than up.

```
def getNth(head, n):
    if n == 0:
        return head.value
    return getNth(head.next, n - 1)
```

This however will perform miserably in practice, and you'll get a stack overflow if your list is any reasonable length. Functional programming style is not usually good Python style (since, for example, tail recursion isn't a feature of Python).

I'd just write the loop out.

```
def getNth(head, n):
   for _ in xrange(n):
       head = head.next
   return head.value
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern in recursion that is cleanly executed in python, so it's worth mentioning.

Methods allow keyword arguments, which are useful for keeping track of recursion depth.  The change to your method signature is trivial:

```
def getNth(head, n, count=0):
```

0 is the *default argument* to `count`.  Just leave it out in your initial call (or explicitly call it with `count=0`) and you're good.  You can then easily recursively call `getNth` with `getNth(*args, count + 1)`.

I should note now that I've explained this that recursion is quite slow in python.  If you care at all about performance you should favor iterative solutions (often involving generators) over recursive solutions.